# Shader Vector "Normal" node how to rotate without input?

Tags: vector

How to calculate the distance in value between 2 vectors? I doing world shader, but I tried to do it in the object shader, everything is the same. I want to get a solid color for math nodes, like "Normal" node, but I can't insert a vector there. By default, this node shows the distance between the vector directed from top to bottom, or if it is rotated then the distance and the value will change accordingly. But I need to calculate the distance between 2 variable vectors for my project. Rotating it manually is not an option. Vector rotate not work, it shows the distance between the "Normal"(upside to bottom) vector to the rotated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question-- maybe you could give more details about your end goal?  "Distance" node will indeed provide the straight line distance between two vectors.  If you're interested instead in the *angle* between two vectors, you can take the arccos of the dot product of the two normalized vectors.

Comment: How to normalize vectors?

Comment: Vector math node.  Normalize is one option for it, just like Distance.

Comment: Okay, I did this. But angle is the value, not image. I tried to do manual math of dot product, same result. Arcosine and other trigonometric formulas multiply image by a certain value. How can I get not an image, but a VALUE? Normalization doesn't matter by the way, my vectors have length 1. https://pastenow.ru/I1RAK

Comment: I don't understand your problem or your questions.  You might consider going into some depth of the reasons you're trying to do this, which would probably give people a better idea of what it was you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a Sun position vector and a Moon position vector. When they are as close as possible - then I need to get 1. When the Sun and Moon are at opposite points - then the value should be 0. This number will be used to calculate the phase of the moon. How can I get this number from 2 vectors?

Comment: The angle ranges from 0 to 180 degrees, but is in radians, so it ranges from 0 to pi.  Divide the angle by pi to remap it to the 0,1 range.  Note that your images don't show you using constant vectors; they mostly show you using generated texture coordinates, which are per-sample values, not constant.

Comment: What vector should I use so that when setting the "Calculate angle" task, I get a numerical value, and not an image of 2 black circles (or a white stripe)? How do I get a number and not an image at all? I've been trying to figure it out for weeks. Multiplying by pi or not by pi, whatever, it only affects the brightness of the previously obtained image.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a combineXYZ node?  A pair of them-- one for your sun vector, one for your moon vector.

Comment: Okay. I will put Sun and Moon vectors to all(or what?) socket of Combine XYZ, but for what??? Okay, I will put Sun and Moon vectors to Separate XYZ and for example put it to Add, and have same result as Vector Distance. Sun and Moon rotated on different axis, I can't take angles(for Vector Rotate) and compare them, need final vector positions, and ANGLE(or distance) between them.